# Swagger Play Framework 2.2 - Joda DateTime Issue

Tags: playframework-2.0, jodatime, swagger

I'm trying to use swagger for my scala Play 2.2 project based on swagger-play2 from wordnik. It seems there's a problem with handling Joda DateTime in swagger. Using the wordnik sample play project, in 'Order' case class,

```
@ApiModel("Order")
case class Order (
  @(ApiModelProperty @field)(position=1)id: Long,
  @(ApiModelProperty @field)(position=2)petId: Long,
  @(ApiModelProperty @field)(position=3)quantity: Int,
  @(ApiModelProperty @field)(position=4)shipDate: DateTime,
  @(ApiModelProperty @field)(position=5)status: String
)
```

I changed the shipDate from java Date to Joda DateTime and it throws an error when I call /store/order API:

```
[JsonMappingException: Class org.joda.time.tz.CachedDateTimeZone has no default constructor; 
can not instantiate default bean value to support 'properties=JsonSerialize.Inclusion.NON_DEFAULT' annotation 
(through reference chain: scala.collection.convert.SeqWrapper[0]->models.Order["shipDate"]->org.joda.time.DateTime["zone"])]
```

Any Idea?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

I had a similar problem. In oder words I did get the same exception.
So, I'll post the solution that worked for me.

The solution was in adapting the BaseApiController.toJsonString(data: Option[Any]) method where the ScalaJsonUtil.mapper is used.

replace

```
ScalaJsonUtil.mapper.writeValueAsString(d)
```

with

```
val m = ScalaJsonUtil.mapper
    m.setSerializationInclusion(JsonInclude.Include.NON_EMPTY)
    m.writeValueAsString(d)
```

JsonInclude.Include.NON_EMPTY is from following import

```
import com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonInclude
```

Answer (score 1):

Alternatively you can use this lib https://github.com/iheartradio/play-swagger

This library takes a different approach than annotation (which force you into learning a new API), you write swagger spec directly in your routes file as comments. It automatically generates definition for joda.datetime.